# Why Python stop working when loads QML file?

Tags: python, qml, qt5, pyqt5

I created the QML file with QtCreator to avoid errors

But when I run the python file, it shows a blank window and then immediately says "Python stopped working"

file.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.load(QUrl('main.qml'))
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
Window{ 
     visible: true
     width: 500 
     height: 400 
}
```

It just crashes everytime, but it runs ok in QtCreator with C++

Comment: What version of PyQt5 and Qt5 do you have? I have run it with PyQt5 5.10.1 and it works correctly.

Comment: Is this file located in resources?

Comment: I have the same version, and I dont know why it crashes, also I tried in a virtual env, and it crashed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, is the cache..!

Yesterday I found a folder in this location:

***C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\cache\qtshadercache***

The thing is that if you create an app in QtCreator, and run it, then if you try to run QML in Python it will crash unless you remove the files in the **qtshadercache** folder, once the files are removed you can run QML in Python, **but you have to remove the files before running QML in Python, only if have used QtCreator before**

I hope this could help someone